# How to convert this function from the styled components package to regular jsx

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I am currently removing styled components from my react app. But I'm having some trouble with the function below. Does anyone have any suggestions? To be a little more clearer. This function sets the opacity and filtered blur. I need it to do the exact same thing, Just in regular JSX.

```
const ImgSrc = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
  style: {
            opacity: `${props.opacity}`,
            filter: `${props.filter}`
         }
}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write `ImgSrc` to be a component which returns the div with the specified properties like

```
const ImgSrc = props => (
  <div styles={{
            opacity: props.opacity,
            filter: props.filter
   }} />
)
```

Comment: Thank you Shubham, I will give that a try.